# I wanted to display all image of current product on a modal

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have an datatable, which display produk (product). each produk has many image. I have problem with get produk id to be used on foreach.

This is my modal view

```
<div id="pictureShows" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="formulir">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" hidden="" id="pictureShowsID" name="pictureShowsID">
        </form>
            @if(count($gambar)>0)
            @foreach($gambar->where('id_prod', $id_prod) as $gb)
            <img id="pictures" src="/liravel/public/{{$gb->lokasi}}">
            @endforeach
            @endif
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Datatable code

```
var g = $('#tabelProduk').DataTable({
        "ajax":"produk/array",
        "language":{"url":"http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/Indonesian.json"},
        "columns":[
        {bSortable: false,
            data:null,
            className: "center",
            render: function(a){
                return"<div class='dropdown'><button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><li class='fa fa-cog'></li></button><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ediProduk' data-id='"+a.id_prod+"' data-jps='"+a.id_jps+"' data-produk='"+a.produk+"' data-deskripsi='"+a.deskripsi+"' class='EditProduk' id='EditProduk'><span class='fa fa-edit'></span>Edit</a></li><li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#hapusProduk' class='HapusProduk' id='HapusProduk' data-id="+a.id_prod+"><span class='fa fa-remove'></span>Hapus</a></li><li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#uploadpicProduks' class='pictureUploadProduks' data-id='"+a.id_prod+"'><span class='fa fa-upload'></span>Upload Gambar</a></li><li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#uploadpicProduk' class='pictureUploadProduk' data-id="+a.id+"><span class='fa fa-upload'></span>Ubah Gambar</a></li><li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#hapusProdukGambar' class='HapusProdukGambar' id='HapusProdukGambar' data-id="+a.id+"><span class='fa fa-remove'></span>Hapus Gambar</a></li></ul></div></ul></div>";
            },
        },
        {"data":"id_prod"},
        {"data":"jps"},
        {"data":"produk"},
        {
                data:null,
                render: function ( data ) {
                    return"<button class='btn btn-default pictureShows' data-id='"+data.id_prod+"' id='pictured' data-target='#pictureShows'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button></form>";
                },
                className: "center"
            },
        ],
        "order":[[0, 'asc']],
    });
    g.on('order.dt search.dt', function(){
        g.column(1, {search:"applied", order:"applied"}).nodes().each(function(cell, i){
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        });
    }).draw();
```

**[Datatable view]**

[image]

I wanted to display all image of each produk on a modal. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put get id on data-target in tag a, and in id modal. dont forget to put inside foreach

```
@foreach($data as $ datas)
<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#pictureShows-$datas->id'>

<div id="pictureShows-{{$datas->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   // code
</div>
@endforeach
```

dont put special char like '?','=',modal will not get the id

Comment: data, it was the product?

Comment: its just for example, you can create your own variable in your controller for different function as you need

Comment: dude, that did it. thanks a lot. nuhun. terima kasih.

Comment: sama sama bro, glad to help